# PHP 5.4 SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm attempting to create a simple php page that demonstrates SQL injection.

```
<?php
  ...

  if ($_POST) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];

    if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='" . $user . "'")) {
      // display result array
    } else {
      // invalid query
    }
  }

  ...
?>
```

The code I am injecting into the html input is `whatever" OR 1=1; DROP TABLE users; --` but it always triggers the invalid query block. How can I trick the script into thinking this SQL is valid?

Comment: put a single quote behind whatever

Comment: This will not always not work, though, because only one query will be allowed to go through .. except for PDO_mysqlnd apparently.

Comment: [`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/mysqli.query) does only execute one single statement.

Comment: First read something about sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I trick the script into thinking this SQL is valid?

You can’t trick it into *thinking* it is valid SQL. You actually have to *make* it valid SQL.

It may help when you echo the resulting SQL statement to see the actual result:

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='" . $user . "'";
echo $stmt;
if ($result = $db->query($stmt)) {
    // …
}
```

Since the injection happens in a [MySQL string literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html), you have to provide SQL fragments that allow you to escape from that string literal. Since the string literal is enclosed within single quotes, a single single quote would denote the end delimiter and any following data is no longer interpreted as string:

```
user: whatever' OR '1'='1
```

This would result in:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='whatever' OR '1'='1'
#                                    \_________________/
#                                         injected
```

Note that [`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/mysqli.query) does only execute one single statement. That’s why the second statement causes an error. So the second `DROP TABLE` statement example doesn’t work here.